# How to calculate probability for a series of trials over the course of a study?

Tags: probability

Suppose I survey many people over the course of a year once per month to see if they were able to complete a trial (they either could or could not).

Most individuals were able to complete the trial every month. Of the people that could not complete the trial, most of the unsuccessful trials were focused in months two and three.

I just want some guidance on how to calculate the probability of success for each month, and the overall probability of having 12 successful trials. Thank you for your input! :)

Comment: The second statement is not indicative of any sampling.  It is too general and does not give a definite number either on the sample size and the proportion of how many of them were unsuccessful.  Am I missing something?

Comment: No, but I could give you some more definite numbers; in month one, 3% of the trials were unsuccessful, in month two, 7% percent of the trials were unsuccessful, and in month three, 9% of the trials were unsuccessful, then in months four to twelve, the success rate is very high, between 96-99%.

Comment: I'm not understanding this.  Are trials independent from month to month?  In other words, if an individual has an unsuccessful trial in month 2, is he/she still present in month 3, and is the chance of having a successful trial assumed to be constant from month to month?  What are the underlying assumptions for the model you wish to use to describe this process?

Comment: All individuals remain in the study no matter what is the outcome of their trial, and the chances of having a successful trial are the same from month to month.

Sorry if it's a bit trivial or complicated, thank you very much for lending your thoughts.